# Webpack: Get list of chunks from inside javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I wanted to access the list of JS chunk files from within entry point Javascript file. Is their a way I can inject it to JS as an array?

**Description:**

For example, I have following JS files:

node_modules

- moment.js
- jquery.js

public

- index.html
- menu.html

src

- shared.js
- utils.js
- main.js (dependent on shared.js & uses moment)
- index.js (dependent on shared.js & uses moment + jquery)
- menu.js (dependent on utils.js & uses moment + jquery)

Now in webpack config I have 3 entry points say main, index, menu. For index & menu, I have related html files and I use HtmlWebPack plugin to inject the chunk files which works well.

But "main" entry point doesn't have any html files and it would be used for some other reason. Here for this entrypoint also it creates multiple dependent chunks say for example (0.js, main.chunk.js, runtime-main.chunk.js).

So for me, from "index.js" file, I wanted to get the list of all the chunks related to "main" entrypoint as array so that I can use those chunks dynamically when the code is getting executed in the browser.

Sample "index.js":

```js
// Currently I am hardcoding this list, which makes me manually update this list whenever I add some more additional dependent files to it.
// I wanted this file list to be populated automatically while the bundling happens so that I need not maintain this list manually.
const filesList = ['/runtime-main.chunk.js','/0.js','main.chunk.js'];

filesList.forEach(file =>{
 // I will do something with this file path
});
```

Mine is a very specific usecase where I definetely need the list of file names dynamically instead of somehow statically loading it. I know I can make use of "webpack-manifest-plugin" which generates the required mapping information as json file which I can use dynamically. But I am looking for a solution where it can somehow injected the list as array itself while bundling the code. I am definetely sure this is possible as I could achieve something similar elsewhere.

Question 2:
For the same usecase above, is their a way I can bundle all the dependency of "main" entrypoint alone as a single file which basically would be "main.chunk.js" so that i can just use that file without need for an array of files.

In advance, thank you for all your answers!!